# 'ERC20: insufficient allowance' when staking

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, erc20

Deployed an ERC20, that is set as an asset for separate staking contract (vault).

I was able to mint, transfer and increase allowance in the ERC20, but when trying to use the 'stake/deposit' function - this return:

`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'`

The address is set as spender + owner, and on-chain calls verified the spender is aprroved under the ERC20.

Any ideas? I suspect it's related to proxy/contract routing.

Tried to stake ERC20 into a staking contract, received 'Allowance insufficient' error.

Answer (score 0):

by any chance did you call the `approve` function on your ERC20 contract to approve the staking contract?

If you did, try to check your allowance again to the staking contract whether it is above the amount that you would like to stake. If the allowance to the staking contract is 0, then it will fail as you essentially have not give any permission from the staking contract to take your ERC20 token fro staking.

To check the token allowance to your staking contract, you can do so by using Moralis

```js
import Moralis  from 'moralis';
import { EvmChain } from '@moralisweb3/evm-utils';

try {
    const chain = EvmChain.ETHEREUM;

    const address = '';

    const ownerAddress = '';

    const spenderAddress = ''

    await Moralis.start({
        apiKey: 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        // ...and any other configuration
    });

    const response = await Moralis.EvmApi.token.getTokenAllowance({
        address,
        chain,
    });

    console.log(response?.result);
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
}
```

where the parameters are:

- `address` is your ERC20 token address
- `chain` is what chain your ERC20 token on
- `ownerAddress` is the address that would like to stake the ERC20 token
- `spenderAddress` is the staking contract

You can follow this tutorial further for more details https://docs.moralis.io/web3-data-api/evm/how-to-get-the-spender-allowance

Hope this helps!